# foreach loop not working with google cloud firestore in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to migrate from real-time database to firestore in react-native with expo. Why won't the foreach loop work now?

**RTDB**

```
firebase.database().ref('messages').child(this.chatID).on('value', snap => {
        let messages = []
        snap.forEach(message => {
            messages.push(message.val())
        })
        this.setState({messages: messages})
    })
```

**Firestore**

```
const unsubChat = firebase.firestore().collection('messages').doc(this.chatID).onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {    
        let messages = []
        const myMesgs = docSnapshot.data()
        if (docSnapshot.data()){
        myMesgs.forEach(message => {
            console.log(message)
        })
        }
    })
```

snap and myMesgs are identical objects. I get a function undefined error when trying to use .foreach on myMesgs. I want to push the value of each object inside myMesgs into an array.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 myMesgs.forEach(message => {
        console.log(message)
    })
```

to this:

```
docSnapshot.forEach(message => {
        console.log(message)
    })
```

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: before the foreach loop add `console.log("data is",docSnapshot.data());` and tell me what the output is

Comment: have you checked the link in the answer?

Comment: Yes it doesn't help

Comment: try it without the if clause

Comment: I ended up just doing Object.values(myMesgs).forEach(message => {
            messages.push(message)

Comment: that seems to work I don't know why it won't recognize docSnapshot as an object